# Получить свойство Protected из объекта

Tags: php, объекты

Приходит от апи ответ. Мне нужно получить некоторые значения из него, но свойство xmlData protected и не могу получить доступ к нему. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?
https://pastebin.com/DxNFREyu

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает публичный интерфейс?

Answer (score 3):

Получить доступ к свойству любого объекта, с любым модификатором доступа, в том числе `protected` свойствам в `PHP` можно с помощью `рефлексий` (**Reflection**)

Привожу пример из [документации](https://php.net/manual/ru/reflectionproperty.getvalue.php) PHP:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static $staticProperty = 'foobar';

    public $property = 'barfoo';
    protected $privateProperty = 'foofoo';
}

$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('Foo');

var_dump($reflectionClass->getProperty('staticProperty')->getValue());
var_dump($reflectionClass->getProperty('property')->getValue(new Foo));

$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('privateProperty');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
var_dump($reflectionProperty->getValue(new Foo));
?>
```

Ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$myObject = new \stdClass(); // объект для примера
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(get_class($myObject));

$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('xmlData');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
var_dump($reflectionProperty->getValue($myObject));
```

Как говорится - если очень хочется, то можно)

Подробнее о [Reflection API](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.reflection.php)